# Dammelo vs dallome

Tags: pronouns, word-order

Perché nelle forme di tipo dammelo, portamelo, ecc. si è preferito l'ordine

```
Verbo + compl. di termine + compl. oggetto
```

a

```
Verbo + compl. oggetto + compl. di termine
```

Quest'ultima forma è per esempio usata in francese or in inglese, e anche in italiano sembra leggermente migliore

> Dai la penna a Luca

di

> Dai a Luca la penna

Comment: Se si potesse dire sarebbe “dallomi”, ma non mi risulta che si dica (almeno in italiano moderno). Perché debba essere migliore, non saprei proprio. La forma c'è, ma come "dallo a me”.

Comment: Dire 'dallommelo' non sembra pazzesco, ma non so perché.

Answer (score 6):

In italiano moderno, [il complemento di termine precede il complemento oggetto nei pronomi accoppiati](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/pronomi-personali_%28La_grammatica_italiana%29/). Si dice *me lo, te ne, glielo*, ecc.
La coppia di pronomi di norma precede il verbo; segue invece il verbo e assume in tutti i casi la forma univerbata con i verbi di modo:

- gerundio
  *giocandomelo / avendomelo giocato

  cantandoglieli / avendoglieli cantati

  parlandocene /avendocene parlato*
- infinito, con la caduta della consonante finale del verbo
  *margiarmeli /avermeli mangiati

  cantarvela / avervela cantata

  giocarcela / avercela giocata*
- più raramente, participio passato, quando introduce una proposizione subordinata
  *giocatomela

  mangiatovelo*
- imperativo
  *cantamelo!

  giocatela!*

Nel caso degli imperativi con troncamento di’, fa’, va’, sta’, da’ l’unione dei pronomi porta al raddoppiamento della consonante iniziale del primo pronome, eccetto il caso della 3a persona singolare:
*dimmelo! vammene! diccelo! diglielo!*

In italiano più antico invece, secondo la [Grammatica ragionata della lingua italiana](https://books.google.se/books?id=RGMVAAAAYAAJ&dq=&pg=PA108#v=twopage&q&f=false) di Carlo Antonio Vanzon (1834), esistevano tutte e due forme:

[image: pagina 108]
[image: pagina 109]

Comment: _“In italiano moderno, il complemento di termine precede il complemento oggetto nei pronomi accoppiati.”_

Questo non è sempre il caso. Per esempio, si dice [“me gli avvicinai,”](https://tinyurl.com/y9hbbth9) non “*gli mi avvicinai,” e [“mi ti sono appiccicata addosso,”](https://tinyurl.com/ydxqdcep), non “*ti mi sono appiccicata addosso.”

In verità i clitici vanno in [un ordine specifico](https://i.imgur.com/OYQvkL5.png). (Patrizia Cordin & Andrea Calabrese, 1988, _I pronomi personali_, in _Grande grammatica italiana di consultazione. Vol. 1_, pagine 589)